# In a forward converter, why do we need a separate controller for secondary side switches?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, isolation

[LT8311](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/8311f.pdf) IC is said to be a synchronous controller IC for a forward controller. Why do we need a separate controller at secondary side as the PWM pulses of primary side should dictate the synchronous switches as well?

Having a driver at secondary side is understandable but having a separate controller is not.

Comment: With an active-clamp forward, you can easily self-drive the synchronous switches but large input variations can bring either too large or too low a drive voltage. A sec. side controller can take care of this. Further, are you familiar with the concept of [pre-bias](https://techweb.rohm.com/knowledge/dcdc/s-dcdc/02-s-dcdc/8360) failures with sync. rect? I believe this IC provides pre-bias protection too. I can see also that the sec. side controller takes care of the feedback without having to suffer from a fast lane issue and it will ease the compensation exercise.

Comment: Yes, self drive will have issues- But for that we can just add drivers at secondary side,  not necessarily controllers.

Comment: Could you please provide some reference for the second issue mentioned- "feedback without having to suffer from a fast lane issue "?

Comment: The *fast-lane* issue relates to the fact that with a TL431 or an open-collector op-amp driving an optocoupler LED, the LED current used for loop control is made of the TL431 section but also from the regulated voltage. And this is the issue. I described this in many of my seminars and the one on [TL431](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/The%20TL431%20in%20Switching%20Power%20Supplies.pdf) in particular.